# User not able to sign out in flutter application

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have the following code for user sign-out.

```
ProfileMenu(
        text: "Log Out",
        icon: "assets/images/power-button-off.png",
        press: () async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
        },
      ),
```

When I press the Log out button I'm shown this

Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.

But still, I'm not able to sign out and go to my opening screen. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

> Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/root');

```js
ProfileMenu(
  text: "Log Out",
  icon: "assets/images/power-button-off.png",
  press: () async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value)=>Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/rootTostartPage'));
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

> await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
> here You are just signing out and not navigating to any screen.

you can navigate your user after above function  finishes.
preferably use navigator push replacement  to clear all previous routes
 `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/root');`